# Having difficulties with scuplting

Tags: sculpting

If the title or username doesn't say it already, I am totally new to this sort of thing. I recently came across blender guru and decided, let's give it a bash.

I am having quite a lot of fun however, I have come across a rather two frustrating problems.

1. Within his video, he has a nice "copper" finish on his donut that allows him to see the depth of indentations quite easily. I tried to achieve the same thing but mine is darker and I really struggle to see or gauge the depth of my indentations.

YouTube video for reference: https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=212

Blender Guru's View:

[image: Blender Guru's View]

My View:

[image: My view for reference]

As you can see mine is dull and makes it really difficult for me to judge depth... am I doing something wrong?

2. In Blender Guru's video, he creates an indentation on the perimeter of the donut using the sculpting brush and it works perfectly on his video.

YouTube video for reference: https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=350

Blender Guru's Video:

[image: Blender Guru's Indentations]

My Attempt:

[image: My attempt]

My brush seems to be affecting more surface area than his brush. I have my brush set to the same settings found in his video:

- Sculpt Tool: Draw Brush
- Radius: 115px
- Strength: 0.263

I have tried different settings, higher strengths but it really messes up the donut. One observation that I did make is that his tool cursor appears to be very different to mine... does that have anything to do with it?

If anyone could help an absolute noob out I would forever be in your debt... busy pulling my hair out here.

Answer (score 2):

In **Sculpt Mode**, Blender uses a 'matcap', one of which is this reddish clay material that lets you judge the surface of your sculptures better. The matcap Blender Guru uses appears to be the default sculpting matcap of *his* version, so if you're using a newer version, chances are you're stuck with the current default until you can find the matcap somewhere online. If you do manage to procure the desired matcap, you'll need to install it, by going to **Edit > Preferences > Lights > MatCaps > Install**.

[image: install matcap]

You can change the matcap in the **Viewport Shading** menu, so even if you can't find the desired matcap, you can always use another built in one, because Blender has quite a large choice!

[image: change matcap]

I also noticed that the icing object seems to be a lot darker than your donut object, and this is because you have **Fade Inactive Geometry** enabled in the **Overlays** menu. To disable it, just click once on the checkbox or bring the slider to zero.

[image: disable fade inactive geometry]

Finally, the most likely reason why your sculpting seems to affect a larger area, despite having the same settings as Blender Guru's, is that the unit of *pixels* is not absolute; depending on how close you are to the object, the area affected changes. You seem to be zoomed out further than the tutorial, which is why you seem to be sculpting a larger area.

If you want the brush size to remain absolute, then you can change the **Radius Unit** by going to **Brush > Radius Unit > Scene**. This will make the **Radius Unit** the current **Scene Unit** (which is *m* by default).

[image: change radius unit to scene unit]

Comment: Thanks @DefaultDucky, I tried following your advice however the brush still affects a much larger area than what I want it to. I tried zooming in closer and applying the Radius scene with correct setting but it still affects a much larger surface.

Not sure what else to do, still trying to figure it out here but it is quite frustrating how the versions change these tools so drastically.

Comment: Does your donut seem to be roughly the same size as Blender Guru's? Another thing that might be causing your brush to be incorrectly sized is if you scaled the donut in Object Mode. So, in Object Mode, press Ctrl A > Apply Scale. Also, can't you just decrease the brush size? Lastly, I had recommended the Scene Unit bit in case you found the 'zoom in = smaller area affected' thing annoying, otherwise you are welcome to use the View Unit so that you can just zoom in or out and you won't have to keep on changing brush size.